# Google Play Policy and Anime Apps

Tags: android, google-play

I don't undersand the new Google Play Policy, I published an App named Naruto Images, but Google Play delete it.
Why?

All images were free and copyless, they say me that I "tried to impersonate another popular app".

So, are the Fan Apps possibles with the new Play Policy?

Thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google policies, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986097?hl=en)

**Impersonation** is when an app attempts to depict itself as another app, person or entity when no such relationship exists.

For example, if your app displays the brand, icon, or title from another app in order to get to users to download your app, you are leading users to believe that your app is developed by the same entity as the other app and offers similar content or experience.

This is an impersonation of the other app and developer, and it is a violation of Google Play policy. If you publish apps that violate impersonation policies, your apps can be suspended and your developer account terminated.

*Here are some guidelines:*

- **Don't pretend to be someone else** — Don't represent that your content is produced by another company or organization if that is not the case.
- **Don't support infringing sites or apps** — Don't divert users or provide links to any other site that mimics Google Play or represents itself as another application or service.
- **Don't use another app's branding**— Don’t try to pass off your app as the official version of someone else’s property by using a person or entity (or brand) name in your app title or description.

Make sure that your app is not violating any kind of contents that leads to impersonation of anyone's identity.